# Gulp Imagemin - recursively

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I have an uploads folder with images inside, without particular folder structure.Is there any way I can compress all images using gulp?
Here is what I tried.

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');

gulp.task('imagemin', () =>
    gulp.src('wp-content/uploads/*')
        .pipe(imagemin())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('wp-content/uploads/*'))
);
```

Comment: Try to use `'wp-content/uploads/**/*.'+(jpeg|jpg|png|gif|svg)`

Comment: In other words: `**` means "directory of any depth" and extensions makes sure that you're not passing non-image uploads to images minificator

Comment: Are you sure this s valid syntax? I get an error - jpeg is not defined?

Comment: sorry, I've mispositioned closing apostrophe, it should be a string at a whole: `'wp-content/uploads/**/*.+(jpeg|jpg|png|gif|svg)'`

Comment: this path should be used as both src and dest ?

Comment: Only `src`, for `dest` you need to define plain path to directory instead of wildcard, `wp-content/uploads` in your case

Comment: works like charm! thank you!